# Не могу убрать круглые скобки в массиве python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.x

У меня python 2.7

мои данные:

```
[('title',), ('Name',)]
```

Мне нужно вытащить вот так

```
['title', 'Name']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это не "круглые скобки", это tuple из одного элемента (об этом говорит запятая после элемента внутри круглых скобок, т.е. `(1)` - просто число в скобках, то же самое что просто 1, а `(1,)` - `tuple` из одного элемента).

Чтобы превратить в обычный "плоский" список, нужно из каждого элемента исходного списка взять первый элемент, и собрать все в новый список.

```
x = [('title',), ('Name',)]
y = [item[0] for item in x]
print y
```

То же самое через цикл for:

```
x = [('title',), ('Name',)]
y = []
for item in x:
    y.append(item[0])

print y
```

Comment: что за item[0]? Все данные лежат в этой переменной column

Comment: @user357670, item - это обрабатываемый элемент списка. Переписал через обычный цикл, может так понятней будет.

Comment: @user357670 если вы задаете подобные вопросы, то могу лишь посоветовать прочесть учебник по питону дальше десятой страницы.

Comment: @insolor извините, нижний цикл я и не заметил